# Overloading Ampersand & operator in R

Tags: r, polymorphism, ampersand

I like to overload my ampersand operator with paste. So that way I can paste stuff easily. Like this:

```
R> "Hello" & " World"
 [1] "Hello World"
```

And the way I achieve this is:

```
"&" <- function(...){paste(..., sep = "")}
```

This is all fine and dandy but you lose the ability to use ampersand as a natural "and" operator.  What would be the best, fastest most beautiful way to overload my ampersand so that it recognizes when the inputs are logical?

```
TRUE & FALSE == FALSE
```

etc.

Comment: Take a look at [this discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/overloading-the-generic-primitive-functions-quot-quot-and-quot-quot-td3016819.html).  In summary, you want to use one of the object like styles in R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use the S3 object system in R:

```
`&` <- function(e1, e2) UseMethod("&", c(e1, e2))
`&.default` <- function(e1, e2) paste(e1, e2)
`&.logical` <- function(e1, e2) .Primitive("&")(e1, e2)
```

Now you can use `&` as you would expect:

```
> 1 & 2
[1] "1 2"
> TRUE & FALSE
[1] FALSE
> "Hello" & "World"
[1] "Hello World"
>
```

Comment: Should the `default` behavior be the logical, and the paste method just for `character`?  Seems much safer.

Comment: Probably, but the way the question was asked made it sound like they wanted to use `paste` except when given a `logical`.

Answer (score 4):

I think defining `&.default` to use `paste` is just wrong:

```
`&` <- function(e1, e2) UseMethod("&", c(e1, e2))
`&.default` <- function(e1, e2) .Primitive("&")(e1, e2)
`&.character` <- function(e1, e2) paste(e1, e2)
"Hello" & "World"
[1] "Hello World"
 1*0
#[1] 0
 1&0
#[1] FALSE
 1&1
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Well, I think creating an overload operator for `paste` is silly given that you can't use any of the very important arguments like `sep` and `collapse`.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, completely disagree.  If you ever have to do any heavy lifting string assembly (e.g. creating HTML programatically), having a concatenate operator is fantastic (e.g. `+` in JS, `.` in PHP).  Though in this case, I would have used `paste0` as the function.

Comment: @BrodieG I wasn't objecting to writing a "paste_all_this_crap" function, but rather to going to all that effort to overload "&" and losing the option to have desired separators, etc.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, but isn't that the point of the operator?  A simpler option that minimizes typing, though obviously at the expense of losing access to the options.  Having to chose between `paste0("<div>", x, "</div>")` vs `"<div>" & x & "</div>"` I definitely prefer the latter, even if it means I can't specify a separator. (and really, I'd like to be able to do `"<div>$x<div>"`, but that's a project for another day).

Comment: Could we set up `&.character` so that the second argument can specify an optional connector that will be used as the 'sep' value? `"x"&"-"&'Y'&'Z'` would return `"x-Y-Z"` The last sentence is rather cryptic, but it made me wonder if a specially constructed environment could be designed.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat, in PHP double quoted strings interpret any variables contained within and substitute the variable contents.  Also, in PHP all variables start with `$`, so if you do something like `$var = "hello"; echo "<div>$var</div>";` the screen output is "<div>hello</div>".  Basically, at some point I want to sit down to see if it is possible to somehow implement this behavior in R.  Almost certainly can't be done directly, but you can imagine how our `&` operator could do some parsing, though with the problem this trick only works if you actually use the `&` operator.  Maybe unary mode?

Comment: Something like that is done with the 'gsubfn' package. Take a look at how it was implemented/

Comment: @BrodieG That's a really good idea to use paste0 instead. On the other hand I disagree with the sentence "losing the option to have desired separators". It's not like I lose the option... if I ever need a special separator I just use paste and it's business as usual.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat, thanks for the heads up on `gsubfn`.  Just glanced through the vignette and looks interesting.  Not sure yet if it is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'd never heard of it and it looks like it does some pretty useful stuff.