# Defining `^.list` for R list?

Tags: r

I want to do this because I define `^` methods for my own S3 class, and it works well. And as I understand, S3 class cannot go into atomic vector without losing class attribute, so for multiple objects I need to use list. But I find it is impossible to define `^.list` and have it work on list.
Here is a simplified example,

```
`^.myobj` <- function(x, y) length(x)^y
x <- structure(c(1,2), class = "myobj")
x^3 
## 8 as expected
`^.list` <- function(xs, y) lapply(xs, function(x)x^y)
list(1,2)^3  
## Error
list(x, x)^3 
## Error
```

Here is another example. I create a package `JuliaCall` which embeds `julia` in R. In the package, there is an S3 class called `JuliaObject` which is a "wrapper" of julia object in R.
https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall
This example is for the illustration purpose, to actually run it, need to have both julia and JuliaCall

```
library(JuliaCall)
julia_setup()
julia_eval("2//3")
## Julia Object of type Rational{Int64}.
## 2//3
julia_eval("2//3")^2L 
## Error
`^.JuliaObject` <- function(x, n) julia_call("^", x, n, need_return = "J")
julia_eval("2//3")^2L
## Julia Object of type Rational{Int64}.
## 4//9
julia_eval("[2//3, 2//3]")
## [[1]]
## Julia Object of type Rational{Int64}.
## 2//3
## [[2]]
## Julia Object of type Rational{Int64}.
## 2//3
julia_eval("[2//3, 2//3]")^2L
## Error
```

Comment: If your function returns a list, you should just add a class to that list. So return a `JuliaObjectList` so you can have a custom method. Changing the behavior for atomic objects can be dangerous.

Comment: I agree with MrFlick, don't try to apply your method to all `list`s, just your own special class of lists. I think this is essentially a dupe of [Overloading the Ampersand & Operator in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21197443/903061) - the same solution works.

Comment: You need to define `\`^\` <- function(e1, e2) UseMethod("^", c(e1, e2));
\`^.default\` <- function(e1, e2) .Primitive("^")(e1,e2);
\`^.list\` <- function(e1, e2) lapply(e1, function(x)x^e2)` , following the lead of the suggested dupe.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for the suggestion. I have considered similar approach. And it is really hard to do this kind of things consistently, since julia may return nested objects back to R. Maybe I should add another class to all the things returned by julia. Really thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I went ahead and closed as dupe. If you're still having trouble, show us in some edits and we can re-open.

Comment: @Gregor Thank you very much. No problem. Could the title of original posts be changed so it can be more searchable?

Comment: Feel free to propose edits. I do think "overloading" should be kept, as [it's an appropriate term for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overloading).